# how does django set up object method before it was defined

Tags: python, django

From django documents, I know if I define a model like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
   SIZE = (
       ('S','Small')
       ('M','Medium')
   )
   size = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = SIZE)
```

Then I have a method for Person called `get_size_display()`.

I wonder how django realizes this feature. How does it know I have a property of `Person` called `size` and use it in the method name? Is this a trick in python?

Comment: See [What is a metaclass in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/100003)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django uses python metaclasses to achieve this.

Much like a regular `class` is a template from which to create objects, a metaclass is is the template from which to create classes.

When you declare a regular `class`:

```
class A(object):
    pass
```

The default metaclass (`type`) is what is responsible for creating `A`.  It does so by processing the things you have defined in `A` in order to create a the object that actually represents `A`.

In Django, the developers changed the metaclass of `models.Model` to their own custom metaclass.  In doing so, they get to control the creation of any class that derives from `models.Model`, and can do the "magic" that you refer to.

Django uses similar magic to do lots of other things, too!

---

For example, I can do the following to replicate what you are seeing Django do:

```
class MetaClass(type):
    @staticmethod
    def _create_getter(attr):
        def _getter(self):
            return getattr(self, attr)
        return _getter

    def __init__(self, name, bases, attrs):
        super(MetaClass, self).__init__(name, bases, attrs)

        for attr in attrs:
            if not attr.startswith('_'):
                setattr(self, 'get_%s' % attr, MetaClass._create_getter(attr))

class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass
```

Now, any class that derives from `Base` will automatically acquire getter methods for each of it public attributes (those not starting with an `_`).

Here's is being used:

```
class A(Base):
    x = 2

a = A()
print a.get_x()
```

Comment: Good explaination! However, stackoverflow says I don't have enough reputation to vote for you.